# AgGrid: How to change the aggregate values for some of the columns dynamically at run time?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-grouping

I am using Ag grid's row grouping feature and for some of the columns I have predefined `aggFunc`.

What I am trying to achieve is that once the grid is loaded with all the data, I want to hide some of the aggregate values (on row as well as leaf children) for some columns based on some conditions.

I checked AgGrid's API docs and tried below but unfortunately nothing works for me.

```
onButtonClick() {
 this.gridApi.forEachNode((node, index) => {
          if (node.field === 'xyz') {
            // node.aggFunc.abc = 0;   // not working
            // node.aggData.abc = null;  // not working
            // node.setDataValue('abc', null);  // not working
          }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
columnApi.setColumnAggFunc(colKey, () => '')
```